# Excel VBA - paste every value in a table column into the location listed in another column of same table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I made an example of a simpler version of the spreadsheet I'm working on. 
On Sheet2 there's a three-column table. First column is the description, second is the value and third is the location I would like the value to be copied to. I would like a macro that will copy and paste every value in the VALUE column to the location in the CELL column and do it for every row in the table.

this table:

| Category | Value | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Height | 5 | Sheet1!C5 |
| Width | 10 | Sheet1!G8 |
| Length | 8 | Sheet1!F15 |
| Diameter | 1.5 | Sheet1!K7 |
| Color | BLUE | Sheet1!F22 |

populates these cells:

[image]

Every location in the CELL column will be on a different sheet in the same workbook. The cell location will keep changing on the spreadsheet I'm working on with different updates.

If one of the rows in the VALUE column is blank I would need it to skip that row, not put a blank in the CELL location but skip the row and go to the next.

I was hoping the table columns could be referenced by name. The table will keep needing to be updated, so I might have to delete some rows or add some rows and didn't want to update the VBA code each time.

Comment: Will those output cells change?  If not you could just use VLOOKUP in the output cells to pull the data.  Otherwise yes you will need vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner I cant put any formulas in the output cells on Sheet1. It's basically an order form that already has formulas in certain cells to help with the filling out. I wanted a way to populate certain parts of the order form without having to edit anything on it.

Comment: if those cells have formula then anything you do will remove the formula from the target cells.  Also just an FYI, This is not a place that teaches how to code or codes for you.  If you have code that does not work, please [edit] the post to include the code and explain where it fails and what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub copy_values()
    Dim src As Variant

    For Each src In Range("A2:A6")
        If src.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Range(src.Offset(0, 2).Value).Value = src.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next src
End Sub
```